# Links on codeigniter website broken on new server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've switched my codeigniter website to a new webhost recently and now all links on the site are broken. Every time i click on one of them website only redirects to index.php.
Everything worked on old server without any problems. I don't know very much about servers, problem is that it's shared hosting and i don't have any access to conf files in /etc/apache2 directory.

My .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: did you change the baseUrl and check the route.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably redirecting everything to `/index.php` because you've got your 404 error document routing to it:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

That would seem to indicate that mod_rewrite *isn't turned on* on your new webhost. You need to contact support and see about getting the rewrite module turned on.

Comment: Nice , thank you. I had just had to enable "sudo a2enmod rewrite" and all worked fine.

Comment: How can I do that? It is enabled, I checked with `a2enmod rewrite` @jon-lin